# How to sum a specific column of replicate rows in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which contains a lot of replicates rows. I would like to sum up the last column of replicates rows and remove the replications at the same time. Could anyone tell me how to do that?
The example is here:

```
name <- c("a","b","c","a","c")
position <- c(192,7,6,192,99)
score <- c(1,2,3,2,5)
df <- data.frame(name,position,score)
> df
  name position score
1    a      192     1
2    b        7     2
3    c        6     3
4    a      192     2
5    c       99     5
#I would like to sum the score together if the first two columns are the 
#same. The ideal result is like this way
  name position score
1    a      192     3
2    b        7     2
3    c        6     3
4    c       99     5
```

Sincerely thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name, position) %>%
  summarise(score = sum(score, na.rm = T))
```